# Test whether a file name has the correct naming convention in Python

Tags: python, nomenclature

How can I test whether a file name has the correct naming convention in Python? Say I want file names to end with the string `_v` and then some number and then `.txt`. How would I do that? I have some example code which expresses my idea, but doesn't actually work:

```
fileName = 'name_v011.txt'
def naming_convention(fileName):
    convention="_v%d.txt"
    if fileName.endswith(convention) == True:
        print "good"
    return
naming_convention(fileName)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a regular expression using Python's [`re` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
import re

if re.match(r'^.*_v\d+\.txt$', filename):
    pass  # valid
else:
    pass  # invalid
```

Let's pick the regular expression apart:

- `^` matches the start of the string
- `.*` matches anything
- `_v` matches `_v` literally
- `\d+` matches one or more digits
- `\.txt` matches `.txt` literally
- `$` matches the end of the string